# Tensor Calculus swapping out repeated indices question

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity, index-notation

Consider the following result from General relativity:

$$(1) \space\space\Gamma^{j}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} (\partial_i g_{jk} + \partial_j g_{ki} - \partial_{k}g_{ij} ) $$

My question is whether it is a general principle in tensor calculus when we have repeated symbols in the same term that these symbols become arbitrary and can be replaced with any other symbol. For instance if we expand (1) as below

$$ (2) \space \space\Gamma^{j}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} \partial_i g_{jk} +  \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} \partial_j g_{ki} -   \frac{1}{2} g^{jk}\partial_{k}g_{ij}  $$

then we can just replace all jk indices however we wish? In doing so then would it be appropriate to write (2) as (3)

$$ (3) \space \space\Gamma^{j}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} g^{jk} \partial_i g_{jk}$$

since the metric tensor $g_{ij} = g_{ji} $ due to its symmetrical nature.

Comment: $(2)$ is not equal to $(3)$. How did you get there? I mean, the symmetry of $g$ just tells you that $g^{jk}\partial_kg_{ij}=g^{jk}\partial_kg_{ji}$, but that doesn't make the third term cancel with the second one.

Comment: Because the second and third term are the same term, given that we can replace k and j with  eachother.

Comment: Aaah, I see what you mean. Didn't see the contraction, sorry. Yeah you are correct.

Comment: I retagged your question. You can see what a tag is about by hovering above the tag name.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
More precisely, you also need the symmetry of $g^{jk}$.
$$\begin{align*}
g^{jk}\partial_jg_{ki}
&= g^{jk}\partial_jg_{ik} & \text{since $g_{ki}=g_{ik}$}\\
&= g^{kj}\partial_kg_{ij} & \text{renaming $j$ and $k$}\\
&= g^{jk}\partial_kg_{ij} & \text{since $g^{kj}=g^{jk}$}
\end{align*}$$
so indeed the second and third terms cancel out.